# ASP.Net on start runs wrong page as Sartup Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a simple folder structure for my multilingual website on localhost

```
Default.aspx
images
css
js
en/Default.aspx
en/ContactUs.aspx
....
ar/Default.aspx
ar/xxxxx.aspx
```

Problem i am facing is very strange to me. i have a simple code to check the browser language set by user and accordingly i redirect user to English or Arabic version of website.

Irrecpective of what code i wring it always redirects me to English version of website and executes the `en/Default.aspx` page

Even commenting all the code in `Default.aspx` page it still redirect it to the `en/Default.aspx` page. while it should not do any thing.

I have set Default.aspx as **Set As Default Page** but it doesn't make any difference. I removed even `global.asa` that had routing code, i also removed all the compiler code related to this website on local host but it still keeps doing the same thing.

I have checked web.config file there is nothing wrong with that.

Even after removing the `Default.aspx` page it sill redirects me to `en/Default.aspx` i am frustrated with this problem.

I am not sure what is wrong. I re-started system with no result.

I am using visual studio 2010 for asp.net web form project.

`http://localhost:49831/AlShindagah/`

ALWAYS take me to below URL

`http://localhost:49831/AlShindagah/en/Default.aspx`

CODE of Default.aspx before i deleted it

```
public partial class DefaultMain : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //switch (Session["lang"].ToString().ToLower())
        //{
        //    case "en-us":
        //        Response.RedirectPermanent("~/en/Default.aspx");
        //        break;
        //    case "ar-ae":
        //        Response.RedirectPermanent("~/ar/Default.aspx");
        //        break;
        //    default:
        //        Response.RedirectPermanent("~/en/Default.aspx");
        //        break;
        //}

    }

    //// Localization and Globalization code
    //protected override void InitializeCulture()
    //{
    //    String lang = Request["Language"];

    //    Session["lang"] = Helper.DetectLanguage(lang);
    //    //Set Direction of page LTR/RTL
    //    if (Session["lang"] == "ar-AE")
    //    {
    //        Session["PageDIR"] = "rtl";
    //    }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        Session["PageDIR"] = "ltr";
    //    }

    //    base.InitializeCulture();
    //}
}
```

Comment: for testing sake try clearing browser cache and history .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had previously used `Response.RedirectPermanent("~/en/Default.aspx");`. A complying browser would remember this and always redirect you there.

Clear your browser cache and try again :)

As a side note, use `Redirect` instead of `RedirectPermanent`. If I'm accessing www.mysite.com from a browser and www.mysite.com `RedirectPermanent`'s me to www.myothersite.com, a complying browser would remember this and for all future requests to www.mysite.com, it would call www.myothersite.com.

Comment: You have mentioned a good point, let me check on that. Will deleting all the cache resolve the issue